# Bootstrap collapse element - collapsing divs not in use

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

We're migrating our college's intranet to a Bootstrap template. In doing so, we wanted to add some collapsible menus for our various constituencies. You can view the result here:

http://www.scrippscollege.edu/intranet/index2.html

Each menu responds correctly by itself (it opens and closes), but how can we make it so that using the Faculty menu closes the Students one, or vice versa?

Updated to add respective code; here's the list items in the menu:

```
<li><a class="nav-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-students" href="#">Students</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-faculty" href="#">Faculty</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-staff" href="#">Staff</a></li>
```

And here is the beginning of each div toggled by the above mentioned code:

```
<div id="menu-students" class="collapse clearfix hidden-phone">

<div id="menu-faculty" class="collapse clearfix hidden-phone">

<div id="menu-staff" class="collapse clearfix hidden-phone">
```

Could the accordion method/taxonomy be applied to the a menu system like ours? All the examples I've seen involve stacked links.

Comment: You should show us your piece of code taking care of the menu, and telling us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the other open `collapse' divs using jQuery. Something like..

```
$('#menu-top-menu [data-toggle=collapse]').on('click', function (e) {
   $('.collapse').not($(this).data("target")).collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: I think there's no need to hack the accordion behaviour when the question asks for the native behaviour of an `accordion-group`.

Comment: Main question didn't really ask for a native behavior, it rather requested similar functionality decoupled from the accordion structure. +1 to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is the native behaviour expected for collapsible elements, make sure you are building a group for the collapsible elements and defining correctly `data-toggle`, `data-parent` and `href` attributes. Follow the example in [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse):

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```